# Sticky Headers with -webkit-overflow-scrolling CSS

Tags: jquery, webkit, scroll, css-position

Using a modified jQuery plugin we have developed a sticky headers scrolling box to imitate the native functionality on iOS in native apps with a cross browser solution that will work on all computers.

Here is the FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/f3y9s/1/

Everything is working including on iOS.

Going further I would like to implement the native smoothing of iOS as well using -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch.

The problem is that this is causing the header to relocate once the scroll is complete rather than whilst scrolling is taking place. Is there any way to fix this. Here is the FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/f3y9s/

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $.fn.stickySectionHeaders = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({ stickyClass : 'sticky', headlineSelector: 'strong'}, options);

    return $(this).each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $(this).find('ul:first').bind('scroll.sticky', function(e) {
        $(this).find('> li').each(function() {
          var $this      = $(this),
              top        = $this.position().top,
              height     = $this.outerHeight(),
              $head      = $this.find(settings.headlineSelector),
              headHeight = $head.outerHeight();

          if (top < 0) {
            $this.addClass(settings.stickyClass).css('paddingTop', headHeight);
            $head.css({
              'top'  : (height + top < headHeight) ? (headHeight - (top + height)) * -1 : '',
              'width': $this.outerWidth() - $head.cssSum('paddingLeft', 'paddingRight')
            });
          } else {
            $this.removeClass(settings.stickyClass).css('paddingTop', '');
          }
        });
      });
    });
  };
  $.fn.cssSum = function() {
    var $self = $(this), sum = 0;
    $(arguments).each(function(i, e) {
      sum += parseInt($self.css(e) || 0, 10);
    });
    return sum;
  };
});

$(function(){
    $('.list').stickySectionHeaders();
});
```

Comment: Whenever I try scrolling on iOS, I find that Javascript seems to stop executing.

Comment: mmm. On the second FIDDLE that is correct and it doesn't trigger until you stop scrolling. Its not a JS problem its to do with when the iOS triggers the scroll event handler, but I don't know enough about how to change that

Comment: That's my point: it's an iOS problem and probably not something that Javascript can fix. Although, you might be able to implement your own scrolling if you intercept the touchmove event and move your contents manually. (It would also allow you to remove the scroll bar.)

Comment: I think you need to use touchmove or touchstart events instead of scroll for iOS.