# Jquery Iphone itunes scroll effect

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css, itunes

Is there a way to replicate the scroll effect that iPhone has in iTunes when scrolling through the songs? The letter sticking on top of the screen and being pushed by the next or replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12219382/364869) where a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f3y9s/1/) that does exactly what you want is mentioned.